# MS Authentication in ASP .net Existing WebForms

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-applications, webforms

I am having ASP .Net Web Application (Web Forms). Want to enable MS authentication on it. How can i add MS authentication in my existing project.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "MS Authentication"? Do you mean the ability to log into your app with a Microsoft account? Or do you mean Active Directory in a corporate environment? Or Azure Active Directory? Or something else? Have you researched how to do it? Tried to implement it? Which part of your implementation are you stuck on?

Comment: Yes. Authenticate with MS account (Azure Active Directory). I can do with new web application. But i need add this on my existing project.

Comment: If you can do it with a new web application, why don't you examine how the new web application does it, then apply the same configuration to your existing web application?